# backbone model, get method does not work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm just a beginner in backbone. And I have a little problem. I fetch my collection and find model:

```
ads = new Somecar.Collections.Ads()
ads.fetch()
ad = ads.first()
```

But when I trying

```
ad.get('color')
```

backbone returns 'undefined', but at the same time

```
ad.attributes.ad.color
```

returns 'black'. What's wrong?
How I can read model attribute through get method?
Thanks

Comment: can you give the console.log of ad.attributes please?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you would need `ad.get('ad').color` based on your `attributes` property. Perhaps you could do this parsing in your collection so that the model's `color` attribute is directly set when fetching the collection:

```
 parse: function(response) {
      return response.ad;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @Herman Tran is right, about `parse:` function. Besides, if you what to access you collection models after fetch, you should write:

```
collectction.fetch({
  success: function (collection) {
    var model = collection.first();
    model.get('attr);
  }
});
```

Since, fetch is async and it's not guranteed that collection is ready while you access it.